# How to pass System.Xml.XmlElement as a pipeline parameter of a custom powershell function?

Tags: xml, powershell

i'm using invoke-restmethod to work with an api.  the response i get from the api is of type System.Xml.XmlElement.  i'm trying to write a few custom functions that can take the output info on the pipeline and then filter down to some other info, but i'm getting the error:  The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline
input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

```
$singleComputer = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Credential $Credentials
function Get-ComputerAttribute
{
[CmdletBinding()]
[Alias()]
[OutputType([int])]
Param
(
    # Param1 help description
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
               Position=0)]
    [System.Xml.XmlNode]$singleComputer
)

Begin
{
}
Process
{
    $singleComputer.extension_attributes.extension_attribute | select name,value
    
}
End
{
}
```

}

This will fail

```
$singleComputer | Get-ComputerAttribute
```

But this will succeed:

```
Get-ComputerAttribute -singleComputer $singleComputer
```

I think this has to do with serialization, which I don't totally understand, but am willing to learn.

The output of $singleComputer (the api response) is:

```
general                : general
location               : location
purchasing             : purchasing
peripherals            : peripherals
hardware               : hardware
certificates           : certificates
security               : security
software               : software
extension_attributes   : extension_attributes
groups_accounts        : groups_accounts
iphones                : iphones
configuration_profiles : configuration_profiles
```

Comment: You need to show details about the output the api gives you.

Comment: Does the variable $singleComputer have a property called 'singleComputer'`? Because that's what your function is expecting when you use 'ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName'. If it doesn't there's your problem, but without a look at the data it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: $singleComputer does not have a singleComputer property.  So I can only use properties on the pipeline?  Is there anything I can do to have access to the entire object?  Can I store the object in a different object, and give it the property name singleComputer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace

```
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
           ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
           Position=0)]
```

by this

```
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
```

I think you don't need all the other information.

Comment: [Please don't put greetings in your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) - they're not necessary, and should be removed.

Comment: While that may work it also unnecessarily removes the other options that he may actually want/need to be there.

Comment: this actually solved my issue for my particular problem.  I didn't realize I could use ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName or ValueFromPipeline. 
Makes sense given my comments and updates to my question. I don't plan on building out too much functionality here, just use the pipeline and other functions to filter down to specific data in the api response.  Maybe not best practice, but I'll just write new functions when I want to target different data in the xml.  This might not work for other people as noted by @PMental